# Install Ubuntu on a laptop without hard drive and without a working LCD

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, usb, display

Old laptop, Vaio Z2, the previous owner took away their hard drive to recover the data. I wanted to turn the laptop into some sort of desktop PC by making it run on a USB liveboot of Ubuntu as I don't have any replacement HDD. The screen doesn't work at all (black) so after reading a bit around I found out I could get the PC to automatically connect to the an external monitor by unplugging the laptop monitor from the motherboard, did that but PC is still not showing anything on the external monitor.

Comment: You're describing several different things and it isn't clear what specific problem you're trying to solve.  You normally don't need to disconnect internal cables to use an external monitor.  It should either display in addition to the built-in display or be selectable from a function key.  If you get nothing on any display, it could be because the graphics card has died.  Have you confirmed it doesn't have a power issue?  re: booting from USB, what boot provision did you install on the USB drive?  Is the laptop pre-UEFI?  (cont'd)

Comment: Do you know if the USB drive works and if it boots on another machine (of the same BIOS type)?  Are you aware that a live session won't be able to save anything unless you modify it for persistence?

Comment: The first thing I'm trying to solve is actually getting an image output, I read on other superuser posts that by unplugging the internal display would force the output to be the external monitor. The USB is working on my main laptop. The laptop I'm trying to fix is a Vaio Z2, not sure if it is pre-UEFI, previous installation was windows 7.

Comment: If your main laptop isn't ancient, there's a good chance that it uses UEFI.  The Vaio probably doesn't if it came with Win 7.  If the USB drive boots your current laptop, there's a good chance that it doesn't have the correct boot provision for the Vaio.

Comment: Main laptop is a 2017 Asus Zenbook Pro so not ancient. How would I find the correct boot provision or correctly manage this? I'm currently creating a live USB using this guide https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows using the same settings reported there. Should I reconnect the monitor to the motherboard?

Comment: The Zenbook uses UEFI.  The Vaio uses BIOS.  So if the USB drive boots the Zenbook, it is probably wrong.  When you use Rufus, be sure to select BIOS rather than UEFI when creating the live session.  If you do it right, it won't boot the Zenbook.

Comment: Retried using these Rufus settings https://imgur.com/a/qasgopw, with main monitor still unplugged, still having no output on HDMI, also using Fn + output keys, no luck. Tried putting capslock on/off and led is turing off/on accordingly so I'm guessing keyboard is working.

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop is booting from USB, then you can do a "real" install on another machine, write the boot loader to the USB device, and use that to boot the laptop from.  Just match the architechture (386 vs amd64) and video card family (nvidia vs ati vs intel) and you should be good to go.

If you install from the server ISO hten video doesn't matter until you install one of the desktop tasks later on, and you'll be able to install the ssh daemon at the same time, then it should be a simple matter of port scanning your local network or monitoring your DHCP server to find the machine on the LAN after booting the laptop.